# How to group a list into a dataframe with four columns?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Let's assume I have a list similar to the one below:

```
l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','L','M','N']
```

I want to create a dataframe that has 4 columns from the fact that every 4 objects in the list is a row. The outcome should be a dataframe with the following form:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4

  A     B       C     D
  
  E     F       G     H

  I     L       M      N
```

Can anyone help me do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert values to numpy array and then use `reshape`:

```
l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','L','M','N']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(l).reshape(-1, 4)).add_prefix('col')
print(df)
  col0 col1 col2 col3
0    A    B    C    D
1    E    F    G    H
2    I    L    M    N
```